# Magento 1 custom Model, Can't get data from table

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I created my own module, the table is created in the database and in a phtml I can call:

```
$res = $model->getExample();
```

and effectively it function is called.

**In Model:**

```
protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('table_name', 'column_id');
}
public function getExample(){
    $result = $this->getData();
}
```

but 'result' is empty and I know there're data in a database, so... what's the problem?

CLUES

```
gettype($this) // is object

$this->load() // Call to a member function load() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

```
Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename')->yourMethod();
```

Comment: I don't understand, I want to get data from the database inside the Model

Answer (score 0):

To get Data from your model you can call your model directly

```
//If you want to load from ID

Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename')->load($id);

// If You want collection

Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename')->getCollection();

// If you want from a method defined in your model

// In your model Define a function

public function getMyData(){
    return $this->getCollection(); // Varien Object
    // return return $this->getCollection()->getData(); // Array
}

Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename')->getMyData();
```